# Deleted Ubuntu partition from Windows7, stuck on GRUB Rescue

Tags: partitioning, grub2

I've been stuck on GRUB Rescue for 1 day now, I deleted the Ubuntu partition from windows7, I had Ubuntu 20.04.1 which is probably the latest version right now, I downloaded it from my USB with balena etcher. after deleting the entire Ubuntu partition I restarted my PC to see if anything would go wrong, I automatically got presented with grub rescue.

The ls command does not work, I cannot boot into Windows from my USB to fix it in the installer because GRUB rescue wont let me, I cant boot into my USB, it shows it as a hard disk, making it bootable or ISO it just doesn't work, and GRUB Rescue will not let me do any other way, what can I do?

Comment: Windows has a command that makes it take ownership of the MBR; this should be run **before** you delete the partition where the prior OS that controlled the MBR, so your machine can reboot.  You got grub rescue because it can't find it's program code (it was found in /boot/grub/ of the partition you erased), and thus it's rather limited with what it can do. It's commands will work, but the rescue tool is tiny having to fit into 512 bytes (thus has minimal functionality).

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 20.04 or the 2020-April release isn't the latest, October (20.10) is a later release, in fact three releases have occurred since 20.04.1 (two the following week, then 20.10 in October)